# Delete item from listBox wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, wxpython

I have this class which deals with listBox:
I tried to make a delete button for listBox items but it didn't work. The "deleteItem" function does now work.Without the marked parts it works good, but there is no delete option. Help someone?

```
class SettingProcess(wx.Frame):
    itemsArr= []
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Black list Proceses",size=(500, 600))
        self.Centre()

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY,size=(500, 600))
        self.index = 0
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)

        lbl_process = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Process name")
        lbl_process.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.txt_processname = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size=(140, -1))
        self.txt_processname.SetValue("chrome.exe")
        sizer.AddMany([lbl_process, self.txt_processname])


        #------------- Files ListBox    -------------------------------------
        global ProcessListMain

        self.files_listBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (12, 130), (200, 240), ProcessListMain,
                        wx.LB_SINGLE | wx.LB_HSCROLL | wx.LB_ALWAYS_SB | wx.LB_SORT)
        self.files_listBox.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 128))

        #-------------  Set event handlers  ---------------------------------
        m_start = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Add")
        m_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddButton)
        sizer.Add(m_start, 0, wx.ALL, 10)


        m_close = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Close")
        m_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onExit)
        sizer.Add(m_close, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        **m_delete = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Delete")
        m_delete.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.deleteItem)
        sizer.Add(m_delete, 0, wx.ALL, 10)**

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def OnAddButton(self,str):
        global ProcessListMain

        #print "value is "+ str(self.txt_processname.GetValue())
        ProcessListMain.append(self.txt_processname.GetValue())
        self.files_listBox.Set(ProcessListMain)

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    ***def deleteItem(self,event):
         numOfItems=self.files_listBox.GetCount()
         for i in range(numOfItems):
             self.itemsArr[i]=self.files_listBox.GetString()
         selectedItems=self.files_listBox.GetStringSelection()
         self.files_listBox.clear()
         for i in numOfItems :
             if self.itemsArr[i]!=selectedItems:
                 self.files_listBox.append( self.itemsArr[i])***
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version, courtesy of Robin Dunn's comment:
Note that I have also bound the `textctrl` so that just filling in a process name and pressing Enter, also acts like the `Add` button.

```
import wx
class SettingProcess(wx.Frame):
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Black list Processes",size=(500, 600))
        self.Centre()

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY,size=(500, 600))
        self.index = 0
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)

        lbl_process = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Process name")
        lbl_process.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.txt_processname = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size=(140, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.txt_processname.SetValue("chrome.exe")
        self.txt_processname.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnAddButton)
        sizer.AddMany([lbl_process, self.txt_processname])


        #------------- Files ListBox    -------------------------------------
        ProcessListMain = ['Process A','Process B','Process C','Process D','Process E']
        self.files_listBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (12, 130), (200, 240), ProcessListMain,
                        wx.LB_SINGLE | wx.LB_HSCROLL | wx.LB_ALWAYS_SB | wx.LB_SORT)
        self.files_listBox.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 128))

        #-------------  Set event handlers  ---------------------------------
        m_start = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Add")
        m_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddButton)
        sizer.Add(m_start, 0, wx.ALL, 10)


        m_close = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Close")
        m_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onExit)
        sizer.Add(m_close, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        m_delete = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Delete")
        m_delete.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.deleteItem)
        sizer.Add(m_delete, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def OnAddButton(self,event):
        Addproc = self.txt_processname.GetValue()
        if Addproc:
            self.files_listBox.Append(Addproc)

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def deleteItem(self,event):
        deleted_item = self.files_listBox.GetSelection()
        self.files_listBox.Delete(deleted_item)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = SettingProcess()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

It's a bit more complicated than having duplicate Id's for your buttons, as I suggested earlier.
Try the following: (I have stuck with your `global` ProcessListMain but had to mock it up, as it isn't declared in your questions code)

```
import wx
class SettingProcess(wx.Frame):
    itemsArr= []
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Black list Processes",size=(500, 600))
        self.Centre()

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY,size=(500, 600))
        self.index = 0
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, hgap=6, vgap=6)

        lbl_process = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Process name")
        lbl_process.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        self.txt_processname = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size=(140, -1))
        self.txt_processname.SetValue("chrome.exe")
        sizer.AddMany([lbl_process, self.txt_processname])


        #------------- Files ListBox    -------------------------------------
        global ProcessListMain
        ProcessListMain = ['123','456','789','1123','2123']
        self.files_listBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (12, 130), (200, 240), ProcessListMain,
                        wx.LB_SINGLE | wx.LB_HSCROLL | wx.LB_ALWAYS_SB | wx.LB_SORT)
        self.files_listBox.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 128))

        #-------------  Set event handlers  ---------------------------------
        m_start = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Add")
        m_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddButton)
        sizer.Add(m_start, 0, wx.ALL, 10)


        m_close = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Close")
        m_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onExit)
        sizer.Add(m_close, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        m_delete = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Delete")
        m_delete.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.deleteItem)
        sizer.Add(m_delete, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def OnAddButton(self,event):
        global ProcessListMain
        Addproc = self.txt_processname.GetValue()
        ProcessListMain.append(Addproc)
        self.files_listBox.Set(ProcessListMain)

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def deleteItem(self,event):
        global ProcessListMain
        deleted_item = self.files_listBox.GetStringSelection()
        numOfItems=self.files_listBox.GetCount()
        itemsArr = []
        for i in range(numOfItems):
            x = self.files_listBox.GetString(i)
            if x != deleted_item:
                itemsArr.append(x)
        ProcessListMain = itemsArr
        self.files_listBox.Clear()
        self.files_listBox.Set(ProcessListMain)
        self.files_listBox.Update()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = SettingProcess()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: what can I write instead of it? if I remove them it's an error

Comment: Or you could just use the `Delete` method inherited from `wx.ItemContainer`: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.ItemContainer.html#wx.ItemContainer.Delete

Comment: @RobinDunn You're correct of course but then I would have had to change the `OnAddButton` function as well to use the `Append` method. I was running with the existing code but your comment is welcome and germane.

Comment: @RobinDunn Code changed to reflect your comment